# Integrating $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^x}\, dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate this.
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^x}\, dx.
$$

Thanks.

I thought
$$
\int_0^1 \ln x \, x^{-x} \, dx=\int_0^1 \ln x\, e^{-x\ln x}\, dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^1 x^n \ln x (\ln x)^n\, dx=\\\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^1 x^n (\ln x)^{n+1}\,dx
$$
but now I am confused because I cannot solve this integral.  I do know that
$$
\int_0^1 x^{-x}\, dx= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}.
$$

Comment: Doesn't the substitution $\ln x = u$ yield something?

Comment: WolframAlpha gives the numerical approximation -1.29129... Assuming this can't be a coincidence, the value of the integral is likely $-1.29129129129129...=-\frac{430}{333}$. The lucky number 333 in the denominator is especially pleasing. ^.^

Comment: @DavidH 
$$
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}\approx -1.29
$$

Comment: I put this into R-Studio. When asked to compute it with $\varepsilon=10^{-10}$, it returned $-1.291285996\ldots$. The answer is clearly not $\frac{430}{333}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a brute force verification of O.L.'s very clever observation, and continuing the approach started in the question,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\log(x)x^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\log(x)e^{-x\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\int_0^1x^k\log(x)^{k+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\int_0^\infty e^{-(k+1)t}(-t)^{k+1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)^{k+2}k!}\int_0^\infty e^{-u}\,u^{k+1}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)^{k+2}k!}(k+1)!\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)^{k+1}}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Brute force.  Thank you...

Answer (score 9):

Since $(x\ln x)'=\ln x+1$, we have
$$x^{-x}(\ln x+1)=-(e^{-x\ln x})'.$$
Integrating both sides of this identity between $0$ and $1$ and using that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}x\ln x= \lim_{x\rightarrow1}x\ln x=0,$$
one finds that the integral we are looking for is equal to minus the [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) constant:
$$\int_0^1x^{-x}\ln x\,dx=-\int_0^1x^{-x}dx=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-n}.$$
No closed expression for this constant is known so far.

Comment: Very clever! (+1)